# How should I represent the conjugate of a term in the denominator?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Using `\overline` for a term in the denominator creates a cluttered look, and `\Bar` results in a really faint line. Also I only know how to use `\Bar` over one letter at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{z_0 - z_1}{\overline{z_0 - z_1}} +
\frac{z_0 - z_1}{\Bar{z}_0 - \Bar{z}_1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to have a line that doesn't clash with the fraction line, but that also doesn't require squinting to observe. What are your recommendations? My best idea right now is to color the line gray, but I don't how to do that.

Edit: Actually, a thin line over the whole term, similar to the one produced by `\Bar`, might just work.

Comment: Please, don't color any line.

Comment: @Sigur "any color so long as it is black" (Henry Ford)

Comment: Not so good solution, but.... `\frac{\,z_0 - z_1\,}{\overline{z_0 - z_1}}`

Comment: Wait a minute... `\overline{z_0 - z_1} = \bar{z}_0 - \bar{z}_1` (if these are complex numbers) and hence the whole expression simplifies to `2 \frac{z_0 - z_1}{\bar{z}_0 - \bar{z}_1}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke The expression is meaningless I just wanted to demonstrate two styles of depicting the conjugate of the denominator. I suppose I shouldn't have separated the terms with a plus sign haha.

Comment: @Sigur as I said to the answer below, that is better than what I have now, but still looks pretty cluttered. Could I make it thinner? Like the line you get with \Bar?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools}
\newcommand{\conjug}[1]{{\fontdimen8\textfont3=0.25pt\mkern2mu\overline{\mkern-1mu #1\mkern-2mu}}\mkern2mu}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{z_0 - z_1}{\conjug{z_0 - z_1}} + \frac{z_0 - z_1}{\Bar{z}_0 - \Bar{z}_1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an improvement over what I have currently, but I feel it's still quite cluttered looking. A thin line in the style of \Bar over both terms would be ideal I think. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: @user475924: I've modified the code to change the rule thickness and defined a `\conjug` command. Is that more like you want?

Comment: @Bernard May be make the change of the fontdimen local? Also `<<<<<<<<<<<<<<; <is tjh` :P

Comment: @Manuel: You're right. I've inserted a pair of braces in the code. I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: @Bernard You had that in your comment, it was just a joke. I see you edited.